# Sinon stub callsFake argument

Tags: javascript, sinon

I had the following stubs running perfectly before

```
sinon.stub(console, 'log', () => {
    // Check what the arguments holds 
    // And either console.info it or do nothing
});
```

For example, adding `console.info(arguments)` inside there, would show me whatever `console.log` was getting.

With version `2xx` I switched to `callsFake`:

```
sinon.stub(console, 'log').callsFake(() => {
    // Check what the arguments holds
    // And either console.info it or do nothing
});
```

This no longer works. `console.info(arguments)` has bazaar values, and nothing to do with what `console.log` is passing.

What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: Try replacing callsFake with returns()

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The arrow function you're passing to `callsFake` doesn't receive the `arguments` object as you would normally expect in a regular function.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

> *An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function expression and does not have its own this, **arguments**, super, or new.target.*

Either change your arrow function to a regular anonymous function (`function() {...}`) or use the spread operator to explicitly unpack the arguments:

```
sinon.stub(console, 'log')
console.log.callsFake((...args) => {
  console.info(args)
});
```